# Generate Xamarin.iOS bindings for HERE SDK 4

Tags: here-api, xamarin.ios-binding

I'm trying to create the Xamarin.iOS bindings for the HERE SDK 4:

```
sudo xcode-select -s  /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app         
cd heresdk-navigate-ios-4.11.0.0.8255/heresdk.xcframework/ios-arm64
sharpie bind -sdk iphoneos14.4 -framework heresdk.framework
```

but I only receive this error:

```
Parsing 1 header files...

Binding...
System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid Image
File name: '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll'
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(string,bool,System.Threading.StackCrawlMark&)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom (System.String assemblyFile) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:367 
  at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.XamarinApiMappingMassager.Initialize () [0x0002c] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/Sharpie.Bind/Massagers/XamarinApiMappingMassager.cs:50 
  no types were parsed that could be bound
```

This is the content of the folder heresdk.framework:

```
% cd heresdk.framework 
% ls -la
total 789992
drwx------  21           672 May  3 17:07 .
drwx------   4           128 May  6 14:03 ..
-rw-------   1          5755 Apr  6 10:53 HERE_logo_full.svg
-rw-------   1          5815 Apr  6 10:53 HERE_logo_full_inverted.svg
drwx------   3            96 May  3 17:06 Headers
-rw-------   1           799 Apr  6 10:52 Info.plist
drwx------   4           128 May  3 17:06 Modules
drwx------   3            96 May  3 17:06 _CodeSignature
-rw-------   1          6106 Apr  6 10:53 arrow_cap_medium.obj
drwx------   9           288 May  3 17:07 geoviz
-rw-------   1     404087792 Apr  6 11:16 heresdk
-rw-------   1          3793 Apr  6 10:53 location_indicator_halo.obj
-rw-------   1         11521 Apr  6 10:53 location_indicator_halo.png
-rw-------   1         20180 Apr  6 10:53 location_indicator_navigation.obj
-rw-------   1         81093 Apr  6 10:53 location_indicator_navigation.png
-rw-------   1         81058 Apr  6 10:53 location_indicator_navigation_gray.png
-rw-------   1         40165 Apr  6 10:53 location_indicator_pedestrian.obj
-rw-------   1         45677 Apr  6 10:53 location_indicator_pedestrian.png
-rw-------   1         45907 Apr  6 10:53 location_indicator_pedestrian_gray.png
drwx------   4           128 May  3 17:06 magma
drwx------  47          1504 May  3 17:07 voice_assets
```

Any ideas what I might missed?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that, we are currently not supporting xamarin. but some customer have  implemented that support on their own in the past. Could you please refer the xamarin official doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website